# unable to install cab file

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have a problem here that i m not able to install the cab file on my emulator. I have followed he steps to make the cab file given on :
http://www.mobilepractices.com/2008/10/setupdll-sample-and-walkthrough-terms.html

then i m copying the cab file on the path "Windows-->Start Menu-->Accessories"

Now when i try to install it from emulator I get this error message..........."Installation was unsuccessful.The program or setting can not be installed because it does not have sufficient system permissions."

one thing to be noted more that even i m not able to configure the emulator-->> i m trying to go to peripherals then when i try to change "Serial Port 0" to "COM3" i get an error message "Unable to open serial port COM3.LastError=The system can find the file specified. "and "Error: Problem updating configuration.Not all settings have been updated."

So is the problem related to my emulator settings or i have some problems with my cab.

if any body knows the solution please tell it ASAP.

regards

Madhup

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand.  You should end up with a CAB file after the build of that sample.  You then have to deploy that CAB file to the device.  Probably the easiest way is to open the emulator, go into the Settings and map a folder on the PC.  That will mount that folder as "Storage Card" on the emulator.  Put the CAB in that PC folder, then on the emulator browse to Storage Card and click it to install.

Answer (score 0):

Hey u change the connection settings from device center to DMA, dont give COM3 and all.. try
it might work,, if still problem persists it would be cabfile problem